# unix query to check if a date falls within a limit

Tags: unix

I have a date variable which stores date like:

```
$date = 20100201  //2010, Feb, 01
```

i want to check if the date i have fetched falls in the month of feb. can someone please help? new to unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (( "${date:4:2}" == "02" ));then echo "February";fi
```

Answer (score 0):

date +%m
gives you direct month number